# use a custom number format for money in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, oracle-apex

i have an interactive report in my apex page with numbers (money) in it, the default money format is U.S which is like this :

```
###,###,###,###.##
```

what i need is this :

```
### ### ### ###,##
```

is there a way to do so in HTML or in CSS or JAVASCRIPT

Comment: Replace `','` with `' '` and `'.'` with `','`

Comment: i keep doing that in SQL query but i got tired of it with too many columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The display format in an apex report is determined by 2 parameters:

- Appearance > Format Mask of the column in your interactive report
- Decimal and Group separator set in the database session.

###### Decimal and group separator

In oracle this is determined at session level. You want `,` as decimal and space as group separator. To change this for your database session run the following statement.

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ', ';
```

- To change this for your entire application, set the following in Shared Components > Security > Database Session > Initialization PL/SQL Code

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE q'!ALTER SESSION SET NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ', '!';
```

- To just set this for the page you have your report on you can either use an application process (with condition Current Page is contained within expression) = "your page" *or* a before header process to execute the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` statement above

###### Format Mask

The Number Format Models [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-096CA64F-1DA3-4C49-A18B-ECC7518EE56C) might give you some clues here: `9`is a NUMBER, `D` is the decimal separator, `G` is the group separator. So you're looking for `999G999G999G999D99`

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(9866166747393/100,'999G999G999G999D99') from dual;

98 661 667 473,93
```

Set this as Appearance > Format Mask of the column in your interactive report.

Comment: didn't try the first solution but the second worked well thanks

Comment: now i have another problem, entering numbers in U.S format (with . as decimal separator) returns an error "field must be numeric", when i use ',' as decimal separator instead it is completely ignored

Comment: This question was about an interactive report - now you're talking about a form. I suggest you raise a new question so it can be picked up in the community. Tackling followup questions in comments is hard and those responses can't help any other forum members. Pls clearly describe how you have implemented the format mask in the form where you're encountering the issue.

Answer (score 2):

How about

[Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat)

or

[toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString)

```js
const number = 10000.50

console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('fr-FR',{minimumFractionDigits:2}).format(number))

console.log(number.toLocaleString('fr-Fr', {
    style: 'currency', 
    currency: 'EUR', 
    minimumFractionDigits: 2 
}));
```